# Did Selected Row App Crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Hello everyone I was following a tutorial where I explain how to expand the cells did with selected row

I've implemented all the array and returns the data correctly but when I go to select the cell to expand my application crashes giving me back this error

> [ PFObject sizeWithFont : constrainedToSize : lineBreakMode :]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

with the breakpoint I find the point but I do not understand what's wrong ...
The point where the app crashes is

```
CGSize AltezzaLabel = [ [ ArrayforPost objectAtIndex : index ] sizew sizeWithFont : [ UIFont fontWithName : @ " Helvetica " size : 14.0f ] constrainedToSize : MAX lineBreakMode : NSLineBreakByCharWrapping ] ;
```

Below I provide the implementation for better understanding

```
#import "FFTimeline.h"
#import "FFCustomCellTimelineSocial.h"

@interface FFTimeline ()
@end

@implementation FFTimeline
@synthesize ArrayforPost, NuovoArray;
@synthesize IsFlashPost;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.FFTableView.delegate = self;
    self.FFTableView.dataSource = self;
    CellaSelezionata = -1;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self QueryForPost];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [ArrayforPost count];

}

-(void)QueryForPost {

    PFQuery *QueryForFriend=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_AMICIZIE_CLASS];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:FF_AMICIZIE_A_USER equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:FF_AMICIZIE_STATO  equalTo:@"Confermato"];
    [QueryForFriend includeKey:FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER];

    PFQuery *QueryYES = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_POST_CLASS];
    [QueryYES whereKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [QueryYES whereKey:FF_POST_SCELTI equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *normalPostByFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: FF_POST_CLASS];
    [normalPostByFriends whereKey: FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE  equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    [normalPostByFriends whereKey: FF_POST_UTENTE matchesKey:FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER inQuery:QueryForFriend];

    PFQuery *normalPostByUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_POST_CLASS];
    [normalPostByUser whereKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE  equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    [normalPostByUser whereKey:FF_POST_UTENTE equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[QueryYES,normalPostByFriends,normalPostByUser]];
    [query includeKey:FF_POST_UTENTE];
    [query orderByDescending:FF_CREATEDAT];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", results);
            ArrayforPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in results) {
                [ArrayforPost addObject:object];
            }
            [self.FFTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];    

}


-(CGFloat)valoreAltezzaCella:(NSInteger)index {

    CGSize MAX = CGSizeMake(230, 10000);
    CGSize AltezzaLabel = [[ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:index] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:MAX lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return AltezzaLabel.height;
}



- (FFCustomCellTimelineSocial *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FFCustomCellTimelineSocial *cell = (FFCustomCellTimelineSocial * )[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellPost"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FFCustomCellTimelineSocial alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellPost"];
    }


    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
        CGFloat AltezzaLabel = [self valoreAltezzaCella: indexPath.row];
        cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.size.width, AltezzaLabel);
    } else {
        cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.size.width, 65);
    }

    PFObject *ObjectPost = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
    NSString *text = [ObjectPost objectForKey:@"Testo"];

    cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel.text = text;
    [cell.FFTestoUtenteLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    cell.backgroundCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.backgroundCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;


    cell.backgroundFotoProfilo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.backgroundFotoProfilo.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0f;

    cell.FFImmagineUtente.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.FFImmagineUtente.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;
    cell.FFImmagineUtente.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;


    PFObject *rowObject = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([[rowObject objectForKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE ] boolValue]) {
            cell.FlashPostImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFNotificaFlash"];
        }

        else {
            cell.FlashPostImg.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@" "];
        }



    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row)

    {
        return [self valoreAltezzaCella:indexPath.row] + 10 * 2;

    }

    else {
        return 65 + 10 * 2;
    }

}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
    if ([self valoreAltezzaCella:indexPath.row] > 65) {
        return indexPath;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
        CellaSelezionata = -1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }

    if (CellaSelezionata >=  0) {
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:CellaSelezionata inSection:0];
        CellaSelezionata = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

    CellaSelezionata = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: Please copy your real code. This code does not compile because it has lots of syntax errors.

Comment: I edited my code by inserting the entire file. m  P.S I'm using Parse.com

Comment: what kind of objects are in ArrayforPost?

Comment: l 'array covers all of the items that I have added to parse the query (PFQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `valoreAltezzaCella:` method, `[ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:index]` is a `PFObject` and not a `NSString`, so you cannot apply `sizeWithFont` to it. You probably want something similar to:

```
PFObject *objectPost = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *text = [objectPost objectForKey:@"Testo"];
CGSize altezzaLabel = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:MAX lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: It works, now the app does not crash and creates the animation on the cell but the full text of the label is not displayed ... What has changed?